# Firefox data-val attribute with placeholder attribute prevents user input

Tags: html, firefox, asp.net-mvc-5, placeholder, validation

This works on the latest versions of all other browsers but fails on Firefox. With Firefox the text-box will not accept keyboard input.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Extension, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = Model.DigitsOnlyClassName, @placeholder = Resources.PhoneExtension } })

<input class="phoneDigitsOnly text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="The field Ext must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '10'." data-val-maxlength-max="10" id="Phone_Extension" name="Phone.Extension" placeholder="Ext" value="" type="text">
```

When you remove either the data-val-maxlength-max attribute or the placeholder the text-box will then accept keyboard inputs.

I've searched but cannot find any specific information about this being a Firefox bug. Is it?

UPDATE: Removing the phoneDigitsOnly from the class also allows the control to work. This class has an event to only allow digits.

It's so strange that removing 1 of the 3 allows for input.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
Would like to know the explanation as to why the bug I encountered only manifested only in Firefox and in such a manner.

I replaced...

```
$('.phoneDigitsOnly').keypress(function (e) {
            if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).match(/[^0-9]/g)) return false;
        });
```

with

```
$('.phoneDigitsOnly').keypress(function (e) {
            var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
            // Don't validate the input if below arrow, delete and backspace keys were pressed 
            if (code == 37 || code == 38 || code == 39 || code == 40 || code == 8 || code == 46) { // Left / Up / Right / Down Arrow, Backspace, Delete keys
                return;
            }
            if (String.fromCharCode(code).match(/[^0-9]/g)) return false;
        });
```

Note the need for the extra key code handling. Again only required for Firefox, arrows, delete and backspace all worked in Chrome & IE latest versions.